# Interview Questions for Javascript Problems

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser

"What is the most difficult problem you faced in web designing (javascript or css related) and how did you debug and solved it?"

This is the question asked to me in an interview. According to my experience I answered it but interviewer expected some more advanced answer from me. Could you pls share with me the problems which you faced and how did you able to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Why the downvotes? Yes, the question isn't worded well, but I think this is still a valid (and interesting) question.

Comment: You can only answer the question. They asked what problem "you" faced and how did "you" solve it. You shouldn't be looking for more complex answers to make you look like somebody you're not, else it'll only trip you up later.

Comment: good point Ira :)  It does seem like this dude is fishing for interview fodder

Comment: Precisely the reason people were voting down the question.

Comment: Hey, I asked the question to the experts, if you are, then answer it properly.

Comment: How are we supposed to know the most difficult problem you've faced in web design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look around here for [javascript questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), you will see the difficult problems people faced and often see how those problems were solved.

For myself, the most difficult thing I have done in javascript is paginate a large web page into many small ones to appear as a book.  I solved it with lots of research and asking a few questions on SO.

Answer (score 18):

Continue to maintain sites for IE6

Comment: +1 Absolutely correct !!! Infact it could have been IE as a whole!

Comment: I know this already. I wanted to know the answer to my question.

Comment: Me too I would like to know the answer :-)

Comment: This answer is nothing to do with my question. Why the people are voting it up!!!  :-)

Comment: Actually, it has everything to do with your question.  It's just vague.  Dealing with IE6 compatibility issues is a difficult problem.  It just doesn't state what those issues are.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the most difficult problem
>   **you** faced in web designing (javascript or css related) and how
>   did **you** debug and solved it?

You see the point I'm making?  Not that asking this question is wrong.  I would ask it for perspective and to get me thinking about my experience.  ("Oh, yeah.  I did something like that once.") However, it seems that you want to substitute the experience of someone else for your own.  Unless the interviewer doesn't know what they're doing, they'll see through it.

Edit: Specifically, I would only ask people to tell me the types of problems they've solved.

Edit2: Then, I'd try to recreate and solve them on my own, if possible.

Edit3: The only thing that comes to mind ATM, is wrapping my head around just what 'this' means in JavaScript.

I also ran into a hairy issue using jQuery to create a tabbed interface.  The close tab icon (an 'X' icon) kept moving around, seemingly at random.  This was also a lot JavaScript event hell.  (The situation where the meaning of 'this' is very important for the structure of the code.)

Comment: ok, at least you can tell the type of problem, I'll try to solve that!

Comment: I've updated my post (as it's easier to read) with the issues that come to mind.

Answer (score 1):

what I meet was consequential loading/saving data from/to web services, calls to which you now are async, we were to introduce an layer receiving all async callbacks and making consequental calls

Answer (score 0):

Biggest JS problem? Having to deal with existing code.

I have pity for those who have to maintain crappy scripts on a daily basis and can hardly blame front end developers and webdesigners for what appears as a reflex: "Uuh! Let's do it from scratch" :)